# Different random number for each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

This code save `1 number` in `localstorage` and the time the number was generated, after 1 minute the item is changed in `localstorage` and shown in htm.

**I'm looking for a way to generate 1 number for each item with an ID**

Example:

```
<div id="now">1 now</div>
<div id="now">5 now</div>
<div id="now">8 now</div>
```

at this moment it shows it like this

```
<div id="now">1 now</div>
<div id="now">1 now</div>
<div id="now">1 now</div>
```

My Code

```
 <div id="now"></div>
```

---

```
function hasOneDayPassed() {
  var lastclear = localStorage.getItem('lastclear'),
    now_p = localStorage.getItem('now_p'),
    time_now = (new Date()).getTime();

  if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60) {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('lastclear', time_now);
    localStorage.setItem('now_p', Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 4);
  }
  $('#now').text(now_p + ' now');
}
hasOneDayPassed();
```

Comment: IDs must be UNIQUE

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the div with id `now-people` and the examples with id `now`. The code you have shown will not produce the result in your example.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm sorry, it was my mistake, I corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` `.each()` function to go through all the elements with class name `.now-people`. Note that I said `class`, as you cannot have more than one element with the same `id`, while you can have multiple elements witht the same `class`.

**Here is an example:**

**Note:** I commented out the `localStorage` (it doesn't work properly on SO) so we can test the `randoms`. In the end we pass an `array` of all the values (changes to `string` with `JSON.stringify()` - localStorage can only take string) to the `localStorage item` `now_p`.

```js
function hasOneDayPassed()
{
    // var lastclear = localStorage.getItem('lastclear');
    
    var now_p = [];
    
    // check if localStorage item is set
    //if (localStorage.getItem('now_p') !== null)
    //{
    //     now_p = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('now_p'));
    //}
    
    // the values of localStorage variable now_p are in the array now_p, to use-> now_p[0], now_p[1] ,...
    
    var rand;
    var time_now = (new Date()).getTime();

/*
    if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60)
    {
      localStorage.clear();
      localStorage.setItem('lastclear', time_now);
*/
      $('.now-people').each(function()
      {
          rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 4;
          this.innerHTML = rand + ' now';
          now_p.push(this.innerHTML);
      });
/*    
      localStorage.setItem('now_p', JSON.stringify(now_p));
    }
*/

// example of mamnaging data input from localStorage
var testJSON = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(now_p) );
// example output
console.log(testJSON);
console.log(testJSON[1]);
}

hasOneDayPassed();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="now-people">1 now</div>
<div class="now-people">5 now</div>
<div class="now-people">8 now</div>
```

Comment: when you run the code for the first time, it works by reloading the page does not show the numbers that are in the localstorage

Comment: @JuanDavid ok one sec

Comment: @JuanDavid I edited with an example on how to check if the value is already set in the `localStorage`, and if it is then perform `JSON.parse()` to return it to an array. You can do anything you want now with the array items. Check the comments. There is example output at the bottom that simulates parsing of the stringified input then accessing the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use different id's, because if you call

```
$('#now-people').text(now_p + ' now');
```

You will override every div with the id now-people.

Comment: Since IDs must be UNIQUE that is likely not the issue